# Refresh part of page after successful user sign in (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my `Index` view of `Home` controller

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.Partial("_UserIsAuthenticated")
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Task/_Tasks.cshtml")
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_UserIsNotAuthenticated")

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_LogIn.cshtml")
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_Registration.cshtml")

}
```

**_UserIsNotAuthenticated** view

```
<div class="col-md-12">To continue <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">sign in</a> or <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrationModal">sign up</a>.
</div>
```

**_UserIsAuthenticated** view

```
<div class="col-md-12"><strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "User")</div>
```

**_LogIn** and **_Registration** are modal windows.
User login and registration work using AJAX, script is below

```
var ajaxLogin = function (submitBtn) {
var $form = $("#login-form");
var $loginAnswer = $form.find("#login-answer");
var answer;
var code;
var messageClass = "";

$loginAnswer.addClass("hide").removeClass("alert-danger alert-success");
submitBtn.html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate'></span> Waiting...").addClass("disabled");

var options = {
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    type: $form.attr("method"),
    data: $form.serialize()
};

$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
    code = data.status;
    answer = data.message;

    messageClass = "";
    if (code === "OK") {
        messageClass = "alert-success";


        setTimeout(function () {
            // close modal and refresh part of the main page
        }, 1000);

    } else if (code === "ERROR") {
        answer = "<strong>Error! </strong>" + answer;
        messageClass = "alert-danger";
    }
    $loginAnswer.find(".answer").html(answer);
    $loginAnswer.addClass(messageClass).removeClass("hide");
})
    .fail(function () {
        code = "ERROR";
        answer = "<strong>Error! </strong>Please, try again.";
        $loginAnswer.find(".answer").html(answer);
        messageClass = "alert-danger";
        $loginAnswer.addClass(messageClass).removeClass("hide");
    })
    .complete(function () {
        submitBtn.html("Sign in").removeClass("disabled");
    });

return false;
};

$body.on("click", "#login-button", function () {
    ajaxLogin($(this));
});

$("#loginModal").on("hidden.bs.modal, show.bs.modal", function () {
    var $form = $("#registration-form");
    $form.find("input[type = text], input[type = password]").val("");
    $form.find("#registration-answer").removeClass("alert-danger alert-success").addClass("hide").find(".answer").html("");
});
```

I would like after successful user sign in to close modal window `$("#loginModal")` and instead if `_UserIsNotAuthenticated` part of page show `_UserIsAuthenticated` part but I don't know how to do that. I don't want to reload entire page (even though it will work the right way), but I want to reload only part of page. Is there any opportunity to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load only authenticated part by making ajax call to an action method that will return your "_UserIsAuthenticated" partial view.
Try like below:

```
public ActionResult AuthenticatedPartial()
{
    return PartialView("_UserIsAuthenticated");
}
```

and

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
             url: "/Home/AuthenticatedPartial",
             success: function(response){
                 $("#container").html(response);
             }
        });
}, 1000);
```

and

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<div id="container">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_UserIsAuthenticated")
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Task/_Tasks.cshtml")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Partial("_UserIsNotAuthenticated")

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_LogIn.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_Registration.cshtml")

    }
</div>
```